# Visualising road segments as heatmap in Leaflet efficiently

Tags: leaflet, webgl, openstreetmap, heatmap, mapbox-gl-js

I have data consisting of parts of road segments of a city, with different number of visits. I want to plot the data on a Map and visualise it in the form of a `heatmap`.

I have two related questions:

1. I have the data from `Open Street Maps (OSM)` in the form of pairs of `node ID`'s, where node ID correspond to the unique ID being assigned to a point by `OSM`. I also have a mapping for each `node Id` to its corresponding coordinates. Is there any `Leaflet` or `Mapbox` utility or plugin, which can plot a trip / highlight the road segment using 2 `node ID`'s. I can always do it manually (by using the coordinate mapping and converting it into `GeoJSON`), but the problem occurs with the line width -- I have to make it exactly overlap with the width of the road, so that it seems that I am highlighting a road segment.
2. Is there any plugin / utility for `Leaflet` or `Mapbox`, which can be used for plotting `polylines` or `geojson` as `heatmap` efficiently? My current approach is calculating the color for each `polyline` and encoding that as a `geojson` property. But the problem is that with the increase in the number of lines (> 1K) the rendering becomes a pain and the method is not feasible. There are [some plugins](https://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#heatmaps) for `Leaflet` out there for plotting `heatmap`, but all of them are for points only and not lines. Any approach using `WebGL` would be really great.

An approach which I thought of could be converting my data into a `shape` file, upload to `Mapbox Studio` and use as a layer directly. But I have no idea how to go about doing that i.e. creating a shapes file, encoding the information in such a way that the complete road segment gets highlighted in the correct color.

Comment: I'm curious what approach did you choose and why?